# How do you use scipy.stats.rv_continuous?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have been looking for a good tutorial or examples of how to use `rv_continuous` and I have not been able to find one.

I read:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous

but it was not really all that helpful (and it lacked any examples of how to use it).

An example of something that I wanted to be able to do is to, specify any probability distributions and being able to call `fit` and then just simply having the pdf that I wanted and be able to call `expect` and get the desired expected value.

The thing I understand so far is that to create any probably distribution, we need to create our own class for it and then subclass `rv_continuous`. Then by specifying a custom `_pdf` or `_cdf` we should be able to simply use every method that `rv_continuous` would provide for us. Like `expect` and `fit` should be available now.

However, the thing that is really mysterious for me is, if we don't tell rv_continuous explicitly what the parameters are that specify the probability distribution, is it really able to do all those methods correctly? How does it even do it just with _pdf or _cdf?

Or did I just misunderstand how it works?

Also, if you can provide a simple example of how it works and how to use `expect` and/or `fit`, it would be awesome! Or maybe a better tutorial or link it would cool.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html

Basically, `rv_continuous` is made for subclassing. Use it if you need a distribution which is not defined in scipy.stats (there are more than 70 of them).

Re how it works. In a nutshell, it uses generic code paths: if your subclass defines `_pdf` and does not define `_logpdf`, then it inherits

```
def _logpdf(self, x, *args):
    return log(self._pdf(x, *args))
```

and a bunch of similar methods (see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py for precise details).

Re parameters. You probably mean shape parameters, do you? They are inferred automagically by `inspect`ing the signature of `_pdf` or `_cdf`, see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L617.
If you want to bypass the inspection, provide `shapes` parameter to the constructor of your instance:

```
class Mydist(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, a, b, c, d):
       return 42
mydist = Mydist(shapes='a, b, c, d')
```

[Strictly speaking, this only applies to scipy 0.13 and above. Earlier versions were using a different mechanism and required the `shapes` attribute.]

Comment: So for example, if I fit some data using KDE (kernel density estimation) and I want to compute its expected value or entropy or something, do I just create a class of rv_continuous, feed my_kde_pdf as the _pdf and then just calling the method expect would yield the corresponding expectation?

Comment: In principle, yes. Assuming that you actually want it, rather than just DIYing the integral for the entropy or whatever expectation value you're after.

Comment: DIYing? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just coding one integral manually might or might not be easier than subclassing rv_continuous etc, that's all I meant.

Comment: yea thats what I did in the end. rv_continuous is too annoying.