# How to generate samples using Inverse Transform Sampling with a given customized PDF in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pdf, data-science, cdf

[The PDF I have is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fr52.png)

```
$$ P(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{4k} \mathrm{sech}^2 \frac{\varepsilon}{2k}$$
```

[CDF:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGqyM.png)

```
$$ CDF(\varepsilon) = \frac{\tanh(\frac{\varepsilon}{2k})}{2} $$
```

[and Inverse CDF:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uttDk.png)

```
$$ CDF^{-1}(c) = \frac{c}{2\tanh^{-1}(2k_BT)} $$
```

Now what should I do to generate N samples, with my PDF P(\varepsilon) of given k?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
def sampleConduction(N, kT):

    for i in range(N):
        c = np.random.random()
        list = [c]
        print('list=',list) 
    g = np.column_stack(list)
    print('g=',g)

     d = np.arctanh(2*list)+2*kT

    return d

sampleConduction(3,0.1)
```

The result of this code is:

```
list= [0.7687170402304889]
list= [0.24759083266582882]
list= [0.18334770166799108]
g= [[0.1833477]]

array([0.38544466, 0.38544466]) # d
```

I wanted to combine the 3 lists into one, but failed by using np.column_stack(). What should I try next?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two comments, not related to the actual question that you ask: (1) Your formula for the inverse CDF does not look correct.  That should be `*`, not `+`, in the formula. (2) The expression `tanh^{-1}(x)` is not `1/tanh(x)`.  `tanh^{-1}` is *the function that is the inverse of the hyperbolic tangent function*.  In numpy, this function is [`numpy.arctanh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctanh.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you! I have corrected my math error.

Comment: Subclassing `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` may be an option. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457754/7207392) for a starting point. This class can generate samples when given only the pdf, but I suspect it will perform better if you also provide the cdf or better still the inverse cdf.

Comment: FYI: Your distribution is known as the [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).  It is implemented in scipy as [scipy.stats.logistic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html).

Comment: If all you need are random variates, numpy has the function [`numpy.random.logistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.logistic.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you! numpy.random.logistic is indeed what I was looking for. I guess I have complicated this problem.